# CancellationToken that cancels after time or manually. Nested cancelation tokes

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellationtokensource

I have async method that takes CancellationToken as parameter so that it can be passed to another method called later. I would like to call that inner method with CancellationToken that cancels after 10s or if "parent" CancellationToken is canceled manually.

I have method A with CancellationToken parameter.
I have method B with CancellationToken parameter called from method A.

I would like to call method B with token that is canceled after 10s or when "original" token that gets passed to method A gets cancelled.

I know I can use `CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))` to get token that canceled after 10s and pass it to method B from A. But I don't know how to cancel method B if token from method A's parameters gets canceled.

Comment: You will likely need 2 `CancellationTokens` for this.

Comment: In addition to @TheGeneral [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.createlinkedtokensource?view=netframework-4.8) might help.

Comment: Have you tried using `CancellationToken.Register` on the first token to schedule the cancellation on the second one using `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter`?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann - That is the answer. If you create full response I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @PauloMorgado adds the same as answer. Accept his one - adding the same answer doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
async Task A(CancellationToken ct)
{
    using (var timoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource(10000))
    {
        using (var combinedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct, timoutCts.Token))
        {
            await B(combinedCts.Token);
        }
    }
}
```